# Constructing 3D image from object layers

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, 3d

So I have a tool that divides the eye (an object) into 32 layers. Is it possible to construct a 3D image of the eye by using these layers? My preferred library would be open CV, but any other python library or non-python library would do

Comment: have a look at volumetric rendering/reconstruction. Maybe you can use something like marching cubes algorithm. In general this is more a computer graphics than a computer vision problem. Maybe there are functions in the point cloud library.

Comment: What kind of image do you want to create? A geometric model (like STL)? A 3D-volumen, like medical CT?

Comment: A medical CT fits the description